# Importing 'marked' module into Angular project returns error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, javascript-marked

I have a project based on Angular 15 in which i recently added marked.
My idea was to use it for a angular pipe to transform MarkDown text to HTML.
However, there is no way i get it working, it doesn't matter how i import it, it always give me errores

I executed:
`npm i marked`
and then:
`npm i --save-dev @types/marked`

And then made up this pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
// import { marked } from 'marked';
import * as marked from 'marked';

@Pipe({
  name: 'mdToHtml'
})
export class MdToHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any): any {
    if (value && value.length > 0) {
      return marked.marked(value);
    }
    return value;
  }

}
```

I tried to import marked like `import { marked } from 'marked';` and `import * as marked from 'marked';` but either way it doesn't work

It returns errors like

```
Error: node_modules/marked/lib/marked.d.ts:613:5 - error TS1383: Only named exports may use 'export type'.

613     export type * from "MarkedOptions";
```

Or it doesn't even compile when using ng serve.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced the same error when I installed [marked](https://www.npmjs.com/package/marked) and [@types/marked](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/marked) with the latest versions in my angular 15 project.

For me, the workaround is to downgrade versions as below

```
"ngx-markdown": "^15.1.2",
"marked": "^4.3.0",
"@types/marked": "^4.3.0",
```

I followed this guide and helped me to resolve this issue https://jfcere.github.io/ngx-markdown/get-started